# Bitbucket README markdown ordered list restarts after code block

Tags: markdown, bitbucket

I'm using Markdown for my README.md on Bitbucket and realize my ordered list restart to 1 after a code block. Here is an example of my text:

```
1. Download VirtualBox
2. Download Vagrant
3. Clone the repository

> git clone URL

4. Go to repository folder

> cd /my_repo

5. Setup your dev environment
```

The number 4 and 5 are both `1.` in my README, which is not what I want. Maybe should I use the `` instead? The result won't be the same style but if my list keep the numbering it would be better at least.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Insert 4 spaces before the blockquotes `>`. This serves two purposes at once: first, it indents the quote, so it aligns with the number above it (as it *is* part of that numbered item). Second, most MD parsers know this means the indented item should not interrupt the numbered list.

Actually, I think you're wrong to use a "block quote". Maybe you should use a *regular* indented 'code' here, using 4 spaces and backticks around your literal code:

1. Clone the repository

   `git clone URL`

(Four spaces and ` around the command line.)

Comment: That's even better. First it would be correctly formatted for code and then the list won't be interrupted, thanks @Jongware!

Comment: This does not seem to work properly for code spanning multiple lines, when used indented in lists. Any ideas if it can be done?

Comment: To add a block of code under a list item, indent by 4 spaces or a tab per nesting level (to nest under the list item), then another 4 spaces or tab (to indicate code block). In other words, to nest a code block under a first-level list item, type your code with 8 leading spaces on each line. You'll also need a blank line before and after the code block. You don't need the backtick characters around the code.

Comment: @TravisG. But then you lose code-highlighting right? I want to keep that!

Answer (score 7):

An even better answer, the general structure should be like this:

```
1. item n.1
2. item n.2

        #!json
        {
            "key": "value"
        }

3. item n.3
```

So:

1. Put a blank line before and after your code block.
2. Indent everything with 8 spaces; no need to 3 backticks before and after the code block.
3. If you want syntax highlighting, put a `#!<language-name>` indented with 8 spaces before your code block.

Bitbucket will respect the list numbering and you won't lose the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize the comments above for users running into this issue on BitBucket here's a snippet of code that I use a README.md boilerplate for my nodejs/express projects that works:

````
**Instructions**

1. Clone the git repo from BitBucket

    ```
    cd *Install_Directory*
    git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
     ```

2. Install/upgrade required npm modules

    ```
     npm update
     ```

3. Run

    ```
    node server.js
    (or)
    nodemon
    ```

4. View tracking dashboard by visiting http://localhost:9988/
````

And for completeness here's the output using StackOverflow's markdown parser:

**Instructions**

1. Clone the git repo from BitBucket

   ```
   cd *Install_Directory*
   git clone https://user@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git
   ```
2. Install/upgrade required npm modules

   ```
    npm update
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   node server.js
   (or)
   nodemon
   ```
4. View tracking dashboard by visiting http://localhost:9988/

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [@Willian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49788815/1956540) solution, try to just indent the code 8 spaces, it seems to enable *basic* block highlighting, not code syntax.  Also, it won't work if you have some bullets nested before the code.  Like if you had a couple bullets nested under #3 before the code.

```
1. First item
2. Second Item
3. Some code example:  

        var a = "Some string";
        function test() {
            return a + "/n";
        }

4. Forth item
```